# How to show images according to boolean in for loop in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array:

```
let categoryNames = [
{color: '#B8E986', background_color: '#69E974'},
{color: '#E94EDF', background_color: '#69E974'},
{color: '#29E986', background_color: '#69E974'},
{color: '#E9DB72', background_color: '#69E974'},
]
```

I also have an array of boolean objects:

```
categoryImages: [
      {isImage1: true},
      {isImage2: false},
      {isImage3: true},
      {isImage4: false},      
    ]
```

I iterate through "categoryNames" array and display data.

```
<div
        class="category-item"
        v-for="category in categoryNames"
        :key="category.name"
        :style="{ 'background-color': category.background_color }"
      >
        <p :style="{ color: category.color }">{{ category.name }}</p>
        <img
          src="../assets/images/icons/bolt.png"
          alt=""
          class="bolt"
        />

      </div>
```

I have an image for every item. Image is the same

**How can I show or hide image according to boolean from array "categoryImages"?**

expected behavior: image 1 is shown, image 2 is hidden, image 3 is shown, image 4 is hidden

current behavior: all images are shown

**EDIT:**
I tried to make it like this:

```
 <img
          src="../assets/images/icons/bolt.png"
          alt=""
          class="bolt"
          v-if="Object.values(categoryImages[categoryIndex])[0]"
        />
```

but it throws an error

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the current category index:

```html
<div v-for="(category, categoryIndex) in categoryNames"
```

Then add a `v-if` directive to your `img` tag:

```html
<img v-if="Object.values(categoryImages[categoryIndex])[0]"
```

Comment: I get an error: "Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: Well, is `categoryImages` defined in `data()`? Is it the same length as `categoryNames`?

Comment: Yes, data: () => ({
    isCardOnDesk: false,
    cardText: "sdfgdfg",
    questionText: "",
    categoryImages: [
      {isImage1: false},
      {isImage2: false},
      {isImage3: false},
      {isImage4: false},
    ],

Comment: I mean, `categoryImages[categoryIndex]` is obviously not working, so did you add `categoryIndex` to your `v-for` directive?

Comment: Now it works! The problem was categoryImages array was less in size. Thank you a lot!